# Search if number is contained within an expression like: 1-3,5,10-15,20

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In an oracle database-table I need to find a result for a given lot-number.
The field where lot-numbers are saved is a string containing something like '1-3,5,10-15,20' (the numbers inside this string are sorted)

is there a way of doing this?

in the example above, the result should be found for the following lot-numbers:

```
1,2,3,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,20
```

There is no way to do it in the application, so it has to be done inside the databse.

something like: "SELECT * FROM products WHERE lot = 2"

Comment: Are you asking for an sql-only solution? Or can you code it in your app? While the first is probably possible, it is not the cleanest of db solutions. Consider inserting the data in a pre-parsed format, like your "following lot-numbers" line.

Comment: what is `result-line`? and what are you trying to find?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to do this all in SQL by use of the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303) function and [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332):

```
with list_of_ids as (
select regexp_substr(a, '[[:digit:]]+',1, 1) as lot1
     , nvl( regexp_substr(a, '(-)([[:digit:]]+)',1, 1, 'i', '2')
          , regexp_substr(a, '[[:digit:]]+',1, 1)) as lot2
  from (select regexp_substr('1-3,5,10-15,20' , '[^,]+', 1, level) as a
          from dual
       connect by regexp_substr('1-3,5,10-15,20' , '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
               )
       )
select a.*
  from products a
  join list_of_ids b
    on a.lot between b.lot1 and b.lot2
```

However, I must emphasise that normalising your database properly is the way to go. This solution may not scale well and does a hugely unnecessary amount of work.

It works like this:

First split your data on the comma:

```
SQL>  select regexp_substr('1-3,5,10-15,20', '[^,]+', 1, level) as a
  2     from dual
  3  connect by regexp_substr('1-3,5,10-15,20', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  4          ;

A
--------------
1-3
5
10-15
20
```

Next, split it on the hyphen to provide a minimum and maximum lot to use in the BETWEEN before finally joining it to the table. The NVL is there to ensure that there is always a maximum.

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(a, '[[:digit:]]+',1, 1) as lot1
  2       , nvl( regexp_substr(a, '(-)([[:digit:]]+)',1, 1, 'i', '2')
  3             , regexp_substr(a, '[[:digit:]]+',1, 1)) as lot2
  4    from (select regexp_substr('1-3,5,10-15,20' , '[^,]+', 1, level) as a
  5            from dual
  6         connect by regexp_substr('1-3,5,10-15,20' , '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  7                 )
  8         ;

LOT1           LOT2
-------------- --------------
1              3
5              5
10             15
20             20

SQL>
```

Here's a working [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be8e0/1) with the full query.

Comment: +1 with the caveat: "normalising your database properly is the way to go. This solution may not scale well and does a hugely unnecessary amount of work."

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution with [PIPELINED FUNCTION](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php):

```
create type array_number
    as table of number
/ 

create or replace function x_tbl(a varchar2) return array_number pipelined  as
token varchar2(10);
str varchar2(1000):=a;
k number;
should_exit boolean;
begin
should_exit := false;
loop
    if instr(str,',') > 0 then 
        token:=substr(str,1,instr(str,',')-1);
    else 
        token := str;
        should_exit:=true;
    end if;
    if instr(token,'-') > 0 then 
        k:=to_number(substr(token, 1, instr(token,'-')-1)) ;
        loop
            pipe row(k);
            k:=k+1;
            exit when k>to_number(substr(token, instr(token,'-')+1)) ;
        end loop;
    else pipe row(token);
    end if;
    --dbms_output.put_line(token);
    --dbms_output.put_line(instr(str,','));
    str:=substr(str, instr(str,',')+1);
    exit when should_exit;
end loop;
end;
/
```

query:

```
select * from table(x_tbl('22-27,33,444-448'));
```

result:

```
22
23
24
25
26
27
33
444
445
446
447
448
```

so, you can:

```
 select 1 from dual where 23 in (select * from  table(x_tbl('22-27,33,444-448')));
```

Answer (score -1):

This is T-SQL but it should not be to hard to port.

```
DECLARE @ranges NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @number INT;

SET @ranges = N'1-3,5,10-15,20';
SET @number = 13;

DECLARE @found BIT;
DECLARE @commaIndex INT;
DECLARE @dashIndex INT;
DECLARE @range NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @rangeStart INT;
DECLARE @rangeEnd INT;

SET @found = 0;

SET @commaIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @ranges);

WHILE (@commaIndex > 0) BEGIN

  SET @range = SUBSTRING(@ranges, 1, @commaIndex - 1);

  SET @dashIndex = CHARINDEX('-', @range);

  IF (@dashIndex > 0) BEGIN

     SET @rangeStart = CAST(SUBSTRING(@range, 1, @dashIndex - 1) AS INT);
     SET @rangeEnd = CAST(SUBSTRING(@range, @dashIndex + 1, LEN(@range) - @dashIndex) AS INT);

  END ELSE BEGIN

     SET @rangeStart = CAST(@range AS INT);
     SET @rangeEnd = @rangeStart;

  END;

  IF ((@rangeStart <= @number) AND (@number <= @rangeEnd)) BEGIN

    SET @found = 1;

    BREAK;

  END;

  SET @ranges = SUBSTRING(@ranges, @commaIndex + 1, LEN(@ranges) - @commaIndex);
  SET @commaIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @ranges);

END;

IF (@found = 1) BEGIN

    PRINT N'Contained.';

END ELSE BEGIN

    PRINT N'Not contained.';

END;
```

Answer (score -4):

This is the simplest solution if you must use SQL only. There are more solutions if you are using PL/SQL. But this could be most efficient and simple. Instead of hard-coded numbers there will be your string of course:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE lot IN (Replace('1-3,5,10-15,20', '-', ',') )
/
```

There is a way to remove/replace more characters in a string if needed. Above example replaces '-' with ',' only...

The question was how to get this:

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE lot = 2..."
```

NOT this:

```
1-3,
2,
4
...
```

State your questions/examples clearly.

Comment: I'm no SQL expert, but I'm pretty sure that this won't work. If you convert all dashes into commas, you've removed the "range" indicator. `2` should match `1-3` but not `1,3`.

Comment: @Tim, you cannot write ranges in SQL such as something IN 1-3... The valid syntax is Select... Where something IN ('1','2','3'...) or "...Where something = 1 OR something = 2...".

Comment: Well, yes. That's kind of the point, isn't it? How does your SQL query match "2"?

Comment: @Tim, see my answer above-edited. And do not rush with conclusions, especially if you are not expert. I answered the question exactly as it was asked and based on given example. Why rush to downgrade? What is the point. You are not even the one who asked the question. How do you know you are correct and I'm not? I think this is dumb softly speaking.

Comment: -1 I am an expert on SQL, and this clearly does not answer the question. You might also want to remember not to take things so personally (no one is downvoting *you*) and to [bring your sense of humor](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette).

Comment: @Expert, so, the simple select where some string IN (some_values) will not work? What is the question: SELECT * FROM products WHERE lot = 2, ...IN ('1-3', 2', '3')... OR SELECT * FROM products WHERE lot BETWEEN 1 And 3... etc... I read it as  SELECT * FROM products WHERE lot IN (some_values) where '-' should be replaced with ','. And all that cr-p with arrays and regexp is not needed to get a simple sting of values... Besides, array is not sql, but PL/SQL. Soooooo many experts...

Comment: It's been in the question from the beginning: *"in the example above, the result (or result-line) should be found for the following lot-numbers: 1,2,3,5,10,11,12,13,14,15,20"*. Your example, replacing '-' with a ',', does not find '2', which was given as an example. Also, the question has been tagged with [oracle] from the beginning which is, as you noted, PL/SQL (not SQL). Of course the OP's syntax was incorrect - if s/he knew how to do what s/he were asking about, s/he wouldn't have asked. Calm down. If you think you are right, leave the question. If you want the rep back, delete it.