# Oracle SQL: Return only values which are contained in a field from another table

Tags: sql, string, oracle, subquery

I am trying to write an Oracle SQL query for to return a set of values which are currently configured to do a job.

I have two tables:

```
VALUES
A
B
C
D


JOB, STRINGS_TO_SEARCH
1    {r, e, 'Hello' A w: B, xyz}
2    {ok, D }
```

The configuration of each job is stored in a single string.  How would I write a query which returns only the values which have been configured for a job?

Is this even possible using built-in Oracle functions?  It seems like I may be asking for a dynamic query to be generated...

Comment: Not completely understanding your request.  What are your desired results from the above data?

Comment: A third table exists with transactional records from scheduled jobs.  Each record has a value (A, B, C, or D) associated with it.  The scheduler can be changed by the user over time, thus the STRINGS_TO_SEARCH can change.  I plan to use the query to identify particular transactional records which have been scheduled for a particular job.

Comment: Given the data in your question, what results do you want?  How are the strings to search delimited, by commas or by spaces?

Comment: I just realized the strings will be formatted like so {junk, values=A:NotA:B:r:e, more_junk}.  So really I need to extract "values=A:NotA:B:r:e" from the field and search between the semi-colons.  The only problem is that the strings are not fixed length.

Comment: The results I want are 1 value per row if the value exists in the search.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table T_VALUES (
   VAL   varchar2(20)
);

insert into T_VALUES values ('A');
insert into T_VALUES values ('B');
insert into T_VALUES values ('C');
insert into T_VALUES values ('D');

create table T_JOBS (
   JOB_ID   int,
   STR_LIST varchar2(50)
);

insert into T_JOBS values (1, 'r, e, ''Hello'' A w: B, xyz');
insert into T_JOBS values (2, 'ok, D ');

select
   job_id,
   val
from
   T_VALUES
   natural join (
      select
         job_id,
         regexp_substr(str_list, '[^ ,]+', 1, occ) as val
      from
         T_JOBS
         cross join (
            select level as occ from dual
            connect by level <= (select max(length(str_list)) from T_JOBS)
         )
   )
order by 1, 2
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebc94/1)

---

**EDIT :**

Improved version (using Ben's idea)

```
create table T_VALUES (
   VAL   varchar2(20)
);

insert into T_VALUES values ('A');
insert into T_VALUES values ('B');
insert into T_VALUES values ('C');
insert into T_VALUES values ('D');

create table T_JOBS (
   JOB_ID   int,
   STR_LIST varchar2(50)
);

insert into T_JOBS values (1, 'junk, values=A:NotA:B:r:e, more_junk');
insert into T_JOBS values (2, 'ok, values=D ');

create type nt_str as table of varchar2(50);

select
   j.job_id,
   v.val
from
   T_JOBS j,
   table(
      cast(
        multiset(
          select
            regexp_substr(
              regexp_substr(j.str_list, 'values=([^, ]+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1), 
              '[^:]+', 1, level)
          from dual
          connect by 
            regexp_substr(
              regexp_substr(j.str_list, 'values=([^, ]+)', 1, 1, 'i', 1), 
              '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null
        ) as nt_str
      )
   ) t
   join T_VALUES v 
     on v.val = t.column_value
order by 1, 2
```

[one more fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83fc8/2)

Comment: Assuming this is the correct way to go you can improve it; you don't need the Cartesian join etc if you `connect by  regexp_substr(str_list, '[^ ,]+', 1, level) is not null` as I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459600/search-if-number-is-contained-within-an-expression-like-1-3-5-10-15-20/14460367#14460367)

Comment: @Ben - Thanks for your hint.  Please look at new code (with correlated subquery) based upon your trick.  It doesn't seem to be shorter.  But probably it will be faster.  Is there exists more elegant way to apply your idea here?