# How to fetch the multiple match string using a regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

My string `2711393|2711441|1234567`

My query is:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('2711393|2711441|2711441', '([0-9]{7})') from DUAL;
```

Actual output is `2711393`.

Expected output is `2711393, 2711441, 2711441`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all of these as a single string in a *row* them there's no need to use regular expressions you can use a standard [`REPLACE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions153.htm#SQLRF00697):

```
SQL> select replace('2711393|2711441|1234567', '|', ', ') from dual;

REPLACE('2711393|2711441|
-------------------------
2711393, 2711441, 1234567
```

If you want all of these in a single column then you need to use [`CONNECT BY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332) as I demonstrate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459600/search-if-number-is-contained-within-an-expression-like-1-3-5-10-15-20/14460367#14460367). Please note that this is highly inefficient.

```
SQL>  select regexp_substr('2711393|2711441|1234567', '[^|]+', 1, level)
  2     from dual
  3  connect by regexp_substr('2711393|2711441|1234567'
  4                           , '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null;

REGEXP_SUBSTR('2711393|2711441|1234567','[^|]+',1,LEVEL)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

2711393
2711441
1234567

SQL>
```

If you want these in different columns you need to use [`PIVOT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) and you'll need to know how many you have. I'm assuming 3.

```
SQL> select *
  2    from (
  3   select regexp_substr('2711393|2711441|1234567', '[^|]+', 1, level) as a
  4        , level as lvl
  5     from dual
  6  connect by regexp_substr('2711393|2711441|1234567'
  7                           , '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null
  8          )
  9   pivot ( max(a)
 10          for lvl in (1,2,3)
 11          )
 12         ;

1          2          3
---------- ---------- ----------
2711393    2711441    1234567

SQL>
```

As you can see these are all completely horrible and, save the first, highly inefficient. You should normalise your database correctly to ensure you don't have to do this.

Comment: If you want to delimit by anything that's not a number you can use `[^[:digit:]]` @sangeethkumar, you'll get a lot of NULL rows though so you'll have to filter these. It's better to remove everything bar a delimiter first.