# Am getting ORA: too many values error while executing this query

Tags: oracle

```
select regexp_replace((select regexp_substr(reference_number, '[^|]+', 1, level), 
                       reference_number 
                       from ups_ship1 
                       connect by regexp_substr(reference_number, '[^|]+', 1, level) 
                           is not null), '(\D+)', '') 
from ups_ship1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without any data but based on your previous question and [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813204/266304), you're passing two columns (your calculated extrated value and the original pipe-delimited string) into `regexp_replace` - which gives the ORA-00913 - and the `regexp_substr()` is returning multiple rows, which is also wrong.

I think you want this:

```
select reference_number, regexp_replace(val, '(\D+)', '')
from (
    select regexp_substr(reference_number, '[^|]+', 1, level) val, 
        reference_number 
        from ups_ship1 
        connect by regexp_substr(reference_number, '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null
);
```

[SQL Fiddle based on your previous question's sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/51893/1), though that doesn't have any data that triggers the replace.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit hard to understand what you're trying to do, but you can't send result of a subquery which returns many rows (with 2 columns) as a first parameter to `regexp_replace`.

You can have the subquery in the FROM clause like this:

```
select regexp_replace(rn, '(\D+)', '') 
from (select regexp_substr(reference_number, '[^|]+', 1, level) rn, 
                       reference_number 
                       from ups_ship1 
                       connect by regexp_substr(reference_number, '[^|]+', 1, level) 
                           is not null) up;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0365a/1)